# Date Diff Function Assistance in Tableau

Tags: formula, tableau-api

I'm using [Tableau Software](http://www.tableausoftware.com) to create a calculated field off of a database, which will be used to dynamically filter the data. Basically, if the date of birth is above 18 as of today, they should be filtered out.

I'm trying to get in a positive integer the difference between the date of birth of an individual (expressed in the database as [DOB]) and today in years. Once I return that date, I would like to evaluate whether it is above or below 18 years. I've been creating a date diff function, but I don't understand what I'm missing.

```
DATEDIFF('year',DATETRUNC('year',NOW()),DATETRUNC('year',[DOB]))
```

References: 
http://onlinehelp.tableausoftware.com/v7.0/pro/online/en-us/functions_functions_date.html

Comment: Just to clarify, what is the actual problem you're having? Are you getting the right integer value but it's negative, or is the calculated field not working at all?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to modify your calculated field slightly so that it returns a positive integer instead of a negative one.

```
DATEDIFF('year',DATETRUNC('year',[DOB]),DATETRUNC('year',NOW()))
```

With that done, right-click in the Dimensions pane and create a new calculated field as follows:

```
IF [Age] < 18 then 1 else 0 END
```

Then drag this second calculated field on to the Filters shelf. When you do that, you'll get a pop-up window where you can select your filter values. Click the checkbox for "1", then OK and that should filter out everyone who is aged 18 or over.

Comment: This calculated field is not correct. It gives the wrong answer for people that are almost, but not yet, 18

Answer (score 0):

The following calculated field returns true if and only if the person is 18 or more as of today

```
datediff('day', [DOB], dateadd('year', -18, today())) >= 0
```